# Voting data in elections for parliamentary speaker position

Tags: data-request, usa, uk, australia

I'm looking for data on votes for the position of Speaker in:

- the House of Representatives (Australia)
- the House of Representatives
  (United States of America)
- the House of Commons (United Kingdom)

preferably for the period 1992 - 2023.